MySQL SELECT com COUNT
I have the following SELECT:
SELECT NrCertificadoPesagem, CodArquivoUsina, Safra, Arquivo 
FROM t413 
WHERE NrCertificadoPesagem<>"00000000" 
GROUP BY NrCertificadoPesagem, CodArquivoUsina, Safra, Arquivo 
ORDER BY NrCertificadoPesagem ASC, CodArquivoUsina ASC, Safra ASC;

... result:

a) I need to include a column "CertificadosQty" which is the count of how many times the certificate is repeated in this same list;
b) Also display only the result of "CertificadosQty" > 1 (greater than 1), that is, the list will look something like this

I even managed to achieve this result, but to do so I had to make 4 selects one within the other, that is, I must have done it the hard way.
I'm already saying thank you to the class :)

StackOverflow is an English website.

I need to include a column "CertificadosQty" which is the count of how many times the certificate is repeated in this same list; Add COUNT(*) AS CertificadosQty to the output list. display only the result of "CertificadosQty" > 1 (greater than 1) Add HAVING CertificadosQty > 1 after GROUP BY.

Hi Akina: I put it as I said, but he ignored "00000001" for example... the list was incomplete.

very poor question description ...

You can run this, too
SELECT
  NrCertificadoPesagem,
  COUNT(*) AS CertificadosQty,
  CodArquivoUsina,
  Safra,
  Arquivo
FROM
  t413 
WHERE
  NrCertificadoPesagem <> "00000000" 
GROUP BY
  NrCertificadoPesagem, CodArquivoUsina, Safra, Arquivo 
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY
  NrCertificadoPesagem ASC, CodArquivoUsina ASC, Safra ASC;


GROUP BY - is to group on each records 

I used what Akira + Abdulla wrote.
But first I had to create a temporary table and use it from this table, because in the grouping I was getting extra rows which, when using count + having, was omitting some records, such as "00000001".
So I just generated the temporary table and then applied the select and it worked :)
I thank you very much. Thank you very much.
